# Rails : No route matches , creating contact us form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, actionmailer, contact-form

I am making a contact us form that doens't have any model. I just want it to be a popup in the home page when people click on contact us.

In the partial we load _contact.html.haml , this is what we have

```
<div class="contact-us-form">

  <h>Contact Us</h>
  <%  form_tag(:controller => "application", :action => "deliver_contact_form",  :method=>'post') do %>
    <p>
      <%= label_tag(:contact_email, "Your Email") %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag(:contact_email) %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= label_tag(:contact_detail, "Details") %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= text_area_tag(:contact_detail,:"", :size=> "44x6") %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
    </p>
  <% end %>  
  <div id="contact_cancel"><%= link_to "Cancel", "javascript:void()"%></div>
</div>
```

and we define the action deliver_contact_form as this in application_controller.rb

```
  def deliver_contact_form
    ContactMailer.welcome_email(params).deliver     
    respond_to do |format|        
      format.html { redirect_to comments_path }
    end
  end
```

when I run just the home page (localhost:3000) I get

```
No route matches {:controller=>"application", :action=>"deliver_contact_form", :method=>"post", :locale=>:en}
```

I was wondering what I need to do?

Thanks,
mina

Comment: What's your `routes.rb` file look like?

Comment: I dont' have anything related to this in my routes.rb, that's why kind of posted this :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the route in your routes.rb

I also suggest creating a new controller, even for a small action like this, anyway:

```
match '/deliver_contact_form' => 'application#deliver_contact_form', :via => :post

<% form_tag(deliver_contact_form_path, :method => 'post') do
```